# Issues reading input from a .txt file

Tags: c++, io, fstream

I'm working on a project that requires that input must be taken from a file and then processed. We were given a skeleton of the code for opening a file and checking to make sure it is open, but I'm having issues opening the file.

**My Code**

```
int main()

{
    readFile();
}

void readFile()
{
    ifstream fin;
    string fileName;
    int x;

    cout << "Enter the file you wish to read from: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    fin.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::in);

    if(!fin.is_open())
    {
        cerr << "Unable to open file " << fileName << endl;
        exit(10);
    }
}
```

My console:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2derI.jpg

We were basically given all of this code so I have absolutely no idea why this isn't working out. This is just a part of my much larger project but I can't even attempt that part yet until I get this working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @PeteBecker: It does, look at the window behind the console.

Comment: 1) Replace your `cerr` line with `perror(fileName.c_str());`. 2) Your process's current working directory isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Yes. If you look at my linked photo it shows my project folder as well. The 12.txt file is in the same directory as the .exe for the progeram.

Comment: @Borgleader - yup, missed that.

Comment: Do you believe that the your current working directory is the same as the directory that contains the exe? That isn't necessarily so.

Comment: Whether the `exe` is in the same directory as `12.txt` is irrelevant. It is the directory in which the process is executing that is important.

Comment: Ok. So I think I found where it executes then and placed 12.txt in there as well but it still isn't able to open it.

http://i.imgur.com/dGztc.jpg?1

Comment: Try to open `12.txt.txt` (maybe your directory settings don't show the extensions and the `.txt` is part of the file name)

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Perfect! Can't believe I was missing that...

Comment: Glad it worked! :) I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your directory settings don't show the files extension. You need to enter `12.txt.txt` instead of `12.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it may have to do with the file name, I compiled and ran this code fine when choosing a different file, but I made a 12.txt file and it produced the same error. It is some issue with the file name being a number I believe, I would suggest renaming the file, though I don't know what makes this occur

Comment: I also tried 12.txt.txt and that did not work, but other files worked fine with just the one extension